# Google maps api v3: geocoding multiple addresses (xml) and creating circles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I was able to get the code below working with a static radius number, but I'd like to pass the radius variable from the XML file to the circle.  I tried using var rad = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('radius')[0].firstChild.data; but that didn't work.  How do I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function geocodeAddress(xmldata)

{

   var address = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
    var city = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.data;
    var address_google_map = address + ', ' + city + ', HI';
    var info_text = address + '<br />' + city + ' HI';

    geocoder.geocode
    ({'address': address_google_map},
    function (results, status)
    {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, info_text);
      } else { 
        alert("geocode of "+ address +" failed:"+status);
      }
    });

  }
 function createMarker(latlng, html)
{

  var marker = new google.maps.Circle
        ({
         **radius: 1000,**
                 strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#0000FF",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
    center: latlng,


            });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(html);
                info_window.open(map, marker);
            });
    bounds.extend(latlng); // Here we tell what are next viewport bounds
}
function initialize ()
{
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.3069,-157.8583);
var myOptions =
{
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    center: myLatLng,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions:
    {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    StreetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
   google.maps.event.addListener
   (map, 'click',
  function ()
  {
    info_window.close();
  });

  downloadUrl('listings.xml',
  function (listings_data)
  {
    listings_data = xmlParse(listings_data);
    var markers = listings_data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('listing');
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{

geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
}
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {map.fitBounds(bounds);});
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<div id="map" style="width:800px; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
<listing>
<address>4123 Rideau Valley Rd</address>
<city>MANOTICK</city>
**<radius>10000</radius>**
</listing>
<listing>
<address>4456 Rideau Valley Rd</address>
<city>MANOTICK</city>
**<radius>20000</radius>**
</listing>
</listings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example of `address` and `city` :

```
var radius = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('radius')[0].firstChild.data;
```

then :

```
createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, info_text, radius);
```

and

```
function createMarker(latlng, html, radius) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius: Number(radius),
        ...
    });
```

Comment: When using var radius nothing happens.  I switched to var rad instead and now it jumps to the middle of nowhere on the map.

Comment: If the expressions that extract address and city work, then I can't see why radius should not be correct ..... except ..... of course, it's a string not a number so it probably needs to be recast with Number(). See edited code above.